# Android Emulator is too slow on Windows Hypervisor Platform

Tags: android, windows, docker, android-emulator, hyper-v

I have to work with Android Studio alongside with Docker for Windows, and as I understand, the best (only?) option for doing this on Windows at the moment is using Windows Hypervisor Platform. The problem is that the Android emulator on this thing is so slow that it's almost unusable. Starting Chrome takes several seconds, opening a simple website takes half a minute. I am new to Android development, so I may be missing something, but I tried everything I could google:

- Virtualization is enabled in BIOS, and of course Windows Hypervisor Platform is enabled as well
- I tried all kinds of images - API Level 28 & 26, x86 (even x86_64), with or without Google Play.
- I tried increasing the image's RAM and Heap size (4096MB and 1024MB respectively).
- Selecting Hardware acceleration in the image options.

Nothing of that helped or even gave me any noticeable improvement. Am I doing something wrong? It seems like Android Emulator is unusable on Windows Hypervisor Platform.

My PC specs: RAM 16GB, Intel i7 2.6 GHz

Comment: try to use genymotion emulator. It won't need that much resources

Comment: Dmitry, did you manage to speed up the emulation?